# Finding out where a Group Policy Object is located (OU Path)

Tags: group-policy

I am currently looking in Group Policy under the 'Group Policy Objects' area. I have found the entry I am interested in however would like to find out which OU that GPO is sitting under.

For example: I'm looking for a GPO named 'Wallpapers', I have no idea which unit this is sitting in because our AD structure is so granular. Could it prehaps be sitting somewhere like DOMAIN > My Business -> London Office -> Third Floor? I don't know???

How can I do this? Also, If I do a search from forest level I can only see a GUID, it does not display a path to where that GPO is sitting under.

I'd like to know the OU the GPO is sitting under so I can figure out what how it is applied.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you expand group policy objects towards the bottom of the group policy console it shows you a complete list of all gpos. Click on one and select the scope tab. It will show you all locations that gpo is linked to. Is that the information you want?

Comment: As @Drifter104, you're probably looking for the link locations, not the objects. All domain GP *objects* are located in `CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=example,DC=org`. *Links* to the GPOs could be in any number of OUs.